# OS drive failure and RAID5 mdadm question

Tags: 12.04, raid, mdadm

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu but I was able to setup my server with RAID5.  The OS resides on a separate drive and there are 3 drives in my array.

The problem is that I had to reinstall my OS on a new drive (currently /dev/sdd) due to a hardware failure and needed to recover my array. mdadm did not create it auto-magically after installing so I followed the instructions SpamapS posted in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11293/rebuild-mdadm-raid5-after-os-hard-drive-died) and got to the point where I recovered the array and could access it using:

mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1

Now in the next step he says that I'll

> want to save the configuration if you have to do that manually:
>
> `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf`
>
> And then update the initramfs for your system:
>
> `update-initramfs -u`

This is where I am not sure how to proceed. I want to make sure that my array will come up after a reboot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you've already assembled the array successfully then the remaining steps need not be feared.

Comment: Actually, he's got all the right steps. The OP merely needs to execute them. My statement was an affirmative one, everything there should work, if it doesn't he'll need to provide more info.